# Why does my .exe file crash after execution

Tags: c

This is a program to store employee details and access them using pointer variables.

The output is getting displayed, but after printing the details, the `.exe` file crashes.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct Emp
{
    char name[30];
    int id;
    char gender[10],mobno[12];
};
int main()
{
   struct Emp *p;
   p=(struct Emp*)malloc(sizeof(struct Emp*));
   printf("\nEnter the employee name : ");
   scanf("%s",&p->name);
   printf("Enter the employee id : ");
   scanf("%d",&p->id);
   printf("Enter your gender : ");
   scanf("%s",&p->gender);
   printf("Enter employee number : ");
   scanf("%s",&p->mobno);

   printf("\nEmployee details:-\nEmployee id : %d\nEmployee name :: %s\nEmployee's Gender : %s\nEmployee's Mobile number : %s\n ",p->id,p->name,p->gender,p->mobno);
   free(p);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(struct Emp*)` should be `sizeof(struct Emp)`

Comment: To avoid such mistakes as pointed out above, use `sizeof *p` instead.

Comment: Also note that in C you [should not cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: `scanf("%s",&p->name)` is a type error.

Answer (score 3):

1. You should `malloc(sizeof(struct Emp))`, not `sizeof(struct Emp*)`. No asterisk, you're allocating space for a whole struct, not for a pointer to it.
2. You should `scanf("%29s", p->name)`. No `&` needed, `p->name` is already a pointer. Also, **that `29` is very important**, you have to limit the size of the scanned string to the available size, otherwise reading more than 29 characters would cause a buffer overflow (considering the final `\0` added by `%s`).
3. Same goes for both `p->gender` (`%9s`, no `&`) and `p->mobno` (`%11s`, no `&`).

Answer (score 0):

malloc should have `sizeof(struct Emp)` instead of `sizeof(struct Emp*)`